# gitignore of Selenium WebDriver TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, git

For selenium webdriver testng using git, what should be part of gitignore so my scripts can run on any computer without any conflict. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like this one (might need some adjustments if you use something other than IntelliJ as your IDE and :

```
# Created by .ignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)
### Java template
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*


### JetBrains template
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion

*.iml

## Directory-based project format:
.idea/
# if you remove the above rule, at least ignore the following:

# User-specific stuff:
# .idea/workspace.xml
# .idea/tasks.xml
# .idea/dictionaries

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
# .idea/dataSources.ids
# .idea/dataSources.xml
# .idea/sqlDataSources.xml
# .idea/dynamic.xml
# .idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
# .idea/gradle.xml
# .idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
# .idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.ipr
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties


### Eclipse template
*.pydevproject
.metadata
.gradle
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.settings/
.loadpath

# Eclipse Core
.project

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# JDT-specific (Eclipse Java Development Tools)
.classpath

# Java annotation processor (APT)
.factorypath

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# sbteclipse plugin
.target

# TeXlipse plugin
.texlipse

# Maven stuff
target/
pom.xml.tag
pom.xml.releaseBackup
pom.xml.versionsBackup
pom.xml.next
release.properties
dependency-reduced-pom.xml
buildNumber.properties
.mvn/timing.properties
# https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper#usage-without-binary-jar
.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
```

If you want to use something other than Maven and IntelliJ you should adjust this .gitignore accordingly

Answer (score 0):

All the files which are local to the project or test execution like .project should be in gitignore file.

Comment: Please give more detail information to defend your sentence.